# V is linear transformation from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ be space of all transformation from $\Bbb{R^3}$ to $\Bbb{R^2}$ under usual addition and scalar multiplication .

Now, what is $\dim{V}$ ?

I am using the fact that in how many ways a basis of $\Bbb{R^3}$ can be used under two binary operation "+,×" to get a element of $\Bbb{R^2}$. Am I right? Please, give me clue!

Comment: If u will use all possible combination u may not get dimension.May be The no. Of independent combination u will have to make for basis.

Comment: Note that this is the same as the space of $2\times 3$ matrices i.e. $M_{2\times 3}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly more general:

- a linear transformation $\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$ is equivalent to a $m \times n$-matrix $M_{m,n}$;
- the space of matrices $M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ form a vector space and from the standard basis, it is clear that its dimenion is $mn$.

Your question follows as a specific case.